# How To Redirect Old Custom domain to New custom domain name on blogger

Tags: blogger

I have a Blogger site which has a custom domain which I want to move one old domain to new. Let's pretend this is olddomain.com and newdomain.com.

If any link to a page has the old custom domain in the URL, and this link is clicked on, it will redirect to a link with the new domain but with the same page. (For example, www.olddomain.com/existing-page.html should redirect to www.newdomain.com/existing-page.html.)

Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect your blog to a custom domain using blogger. Here, what happens is that all hits your blogspot domain will be redirected to your new domain.

`www.olddomain.blogpsot.com/existing-page.html` to `www.olddomain.com/existing-page.html`

This can be achieved by setting up the `Cname` and `A name` records.

If you have a new domain, then you can set it as your new redirect as :

`www.olddomain.blogpsot.com/existing-page.html` to  `www.newdomain.com/existing-page.html`

But you can't redirect from `www.olddomain.com/existing-page.html`  to `www.newdomain.com/existing-page.html` using blogger settings. This is because the domains are not handled by blogpsot.

Either you should check for options with your domain provider to set up a re direct or point your old domain to a new blog and set a redirect to new url (Give a link to new url and notify users that you have shifted the domain).